# How to exploit the possibilites of blockchain for proof of authorship?

Tags: blockchain

I want to to create some kind of Proof-of-Authorship mechanism, that's something that many artists had asked before: [How can I prove authorship of my work](http://ask.metafilter.com/96453/how-can-I-prove-authorship-of-my-work)

To accomplish my objective I need to deal with 2 problems:

- first, how to precisely and uniquely define a work, and
- second, use something like a public ledger to store and validate that information.

I will think about first later; it's a very complex problem; I want to know if I could use the blockchain for the second one. (If you can give me some suggestions for the first problem they will be appreciated too.)

Comment: It already exists: http://www.proofofexistence.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If expressing the (artistic) work in any kind of document (be it sheets, photos or audio/video recording) is good enough, then you can use something called [proof of existence](/questions/19038/are-there-any-non-monetary-uses-for-the-blockchain-or-the-bitcoin-protocol-gene/19041#19041). This simple method allows you to store a hash of any document into the Blockchain, thus proving it existed at the time when a particular block was mined.

You can indlude the **autor's name** (or other identifier) into the document, making it clear that he (at least) knew about it back then. If nobody proves the possesion/familiarity with that particular file/work dated before, the author should be able to claim his rights.

One (perhaps the first) proof-of-existence service is [proofofexistence.com](http://www.proofofexistence.com/).

Comment: Mmmh, so there was already a possibility there, but don't seems so popular, I have been in the Crypto-world for a long time and never heard about that. Maybe I will try to promote it or create similar improved system. Thanks for the info

Comment: There is now a service called [ascribe](http://www.ascribe.io). It combines blockchain hashes for verification with a website for browsing.